# Identify bush with small separate berries and leaves like a rose bush

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify a wild growing bush located in the Northeast USA that is similar to a cotoneaster, but has some differences. Here are the features:

1. the berries grow at the ends of dendritic stems and are less than 1/4 inch in diameter but greater than 3/16". The berries are slightly longer than wide. They are not round.
2. the berries are separate from each other by about 1/2" and do not touch each other
3. the berries are reddish orange
4. the leaves are exactly like those of a rose bush, oval and having a serrated edge (this excludes the cotoneaster)
5. the bush grows much like a rose bush

Comment: Do you happen to have a few photos for us?

Comment: A photo  would confirm, but could they not just be rosehips?

Comment: @Bamboo Maybe. Can rosehips be 3/16" in diameter?

Comment: @AndreLenotre Yes, depending on the rose species. The common wild "dog rose" *rosa canina* often has hips more than 1/2 inch diameter.

Comment: Possible, yes, but a photo would confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending photographic confirmation, I'm going out on a limb and saying that the plant is a m[ultiflora rose](http://www.coldclimategardening.com/2014/06/25/wild-wicked-but-not-native-rosa-multiflora/). Oddly, it's surprisingly hard to find a good photo of this invasive weed. The berries' shape, diameter, and growth habit all match those of the multiflora.

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks like a strong possibility. I will confirm it tomorrow.